# fit hyperbola from data points

Tags: python, math, function-approximation

I have experimental data points (x1, x2, ..., xn), (y1, y2, ..., yn) of turbocharger pressure map and want to get trendline equation. In result of my research it's something like:

```
y = (ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f)/(x+g)    # my equation
```

Tell me please, are there any ready-made functions for this?
I tried using np.polyfit, but it works with usual polynoms and I must guess "g" in this way:

```
# y*(x-g) = ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f
pc  = np.polyfit(x, y*(x+g), 5)
y = (pc[0]*x**5 + pc[1]*x**4 + pc[2]*x**3 + pc[3]*x**2 + pc[4]*x + pc[5])/(x + g)
```

It would be nice if someone could help to get coefficiens of my equation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `x + g`or `x - g`?

Comment: -g because it always negative. But while we looking for it it doesn`t matter, seems

Comment: @ray_med: it does matter to have coherent quations.

Answer (score 0):

Though this will lead to a slightly different minimization, you can linearize the equation as

```
x y = ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f - g y
```

and solve by linear least-squares.

Comment: It doesn`t work, because we have constant term = `f + g y`. Even if f =0, we have g=pc[5]/y and it is not computable

Comment: @ray_med: it does work, it is an overdetermined system in 7 unknowns. But you are not obliged to believe me.